# Hierarchical RSS Feeds

Tags: xml, rss

Is it possible to create an RSS feed with a multi-level hierarchy, sort of like a directory structure?   Is this allowed per the RSS spec?
If this is possible, does anyone know of what limitations there might be?  As in, are there any particular readers that would not support it?
My main concern here is that I want to create an RSS feed to use with the "Live Bookmarks" feature in many browsers, but be able to maintain the directory feel.

I'm not concerned with the code to generate the RSS, though an example of what the RSS xml would look like would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible per the [Rss Spec](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html), and if you attempt to do so i'm afraid that a lot of browsers will not recognize rss format.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you could do is let the < link > Elements point to other rss feeds.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that its been a while since the OP asked this question, but I've been thinking of doing something similar recently - My problem is representing an HTML page with multiple components (tiles) as an RSS feed. I am thinking of just embedding the XPath to the component (from the main page) as a rss/item/category tag:

<item>
  ...
  <category domain="path">/component1/subcomponent2</category>
</item>

Hopefully this helps someone else that comes looking :-).